# How to use graphviz to show graph like this

Tags: graphviz, dot

[image]

I used word to make this graph, how to make it in dot language? The line style is perpendicular. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'pos' attribute to place your nodes on an imaginary grid:

```
graph X
{
  a [pos="1,1"]
  b [pos="2,2"]
  c [pos="2,3"]
  d [pos="2,4"]
}
```

and then use the appropriate flag to the layout program to override neato's desire to place your nodes (you may also need to fiddle with the size of your nodes). You probably end up with edges which are not straight. In that case, define invisible nodes for the junction points on your imaginary grid and draw edges from your top node to the invisible ones and from the invisible ones to RIL_Init and so on. If your graphs are big, this will get pretty tedious..still straightforward...and you still get all the output options of graphviz. The need for pos="1,1!" usually comes up too, the bang meaning 'put it exactly there'.